# Getting NaN values when multiplying a number by document.getElementById('myid')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JavaScript. I want to make subtotal for each product and I don't know why I keep getting `NaN`? Here is my code. I couldn't find the problem for this. Maybe there's something wrong with the value or something?

```js
    var value;

    var price = document.getElementById("price");

    function priceTotal() {
        var total = value * price;
        document.getElementById("subtotal").innerText = total;
    }

    $('.increment-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var incre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val();
        var value = parseInt(incre_value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value < 100) {
            value++;
            $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val(value);
        }

        priceTotal();
    });

    $('.decrement-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var decre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val();
        var value = parseInt(decre_value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value > 1) {
            value--;
            $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val(value);
        }

        priceTotal();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="text-center" id="price">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</td>
                                <td class="cart-product-quantity text-center" width="132px">
                                    <div class="input-group quantity">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend decrement-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="qty-input form-control text-center" maxlength="2" value="1" id="qty-input">
                                        <div class="input-group-append increment-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">+</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <!-- <input style="text-align:center; width: 70px;" type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" value="{{$cartlist->product->productprice}}" > -->
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span id="subtotal">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</span>
                                </td>
```

Comment: There may be other issues, but for starters, you have `var price = document.getElementById("price");` and then you attempt to do `var total = value * price;`. The problem here is that `price` isn't the ***value*** of the HTML element, it's a reference to the element itself and you can't do math with an element. So, you'd need: `var total = value * price.textContent;` (assuming that `price` points to the `td` element).

Comment: yes, i change it into `var price = parseInt($("#price").text());` now its working. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- 1 -- You need to pass `value` from the `onClick()` handler to the `priceTotal()` function.  I recommend you take a quick glance at [MDN Web Docs: Encapsulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Encapsulation), specifically:

> Encapsulation is the packing of data and functions into one component (for example, a class) and then controlling access to that component to make a "blackbox" out of the object.

- 2 -- You are setting price to `var price = document.getElementById("price");` and then using it in multiplication.  You cannot do that, you must use a number in multiplication, not an HTML element.  In addition, the price element *is not* even an input, so you can't use its `val()` function either.  I set this statically to just `1` to prove my point.

```js
    var value;

    var price = 1; // you can't use an element as an integer

    function priceTotal(value) {
        var total = value * price;
        document.getElementById("subtotal").innerText = total;
    }

    $('.increment-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var incre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val();
        var value = parseInt(incre_value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value < 100) {
            value++;
            $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val(value);
        }

        priceTotal(value);
    });

    $('.decrement-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var decre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val();
        var value = parseInt(decre_value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value > 1) {
            value--;
            $(this).parents('.quantity').find('#qty-input').val(value);
        }

        priceTotal(value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="text-center" id="price">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</td>
                                <td class="cart-product-quantity text-center" width="132px">
                                    <div class="input-group quantity">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend decrement-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="qty-input form-control text-center" maxlength="2" value="1" id="qty-input">
                                        <div class="input-group-append increment-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">+</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <!-- <input style="text-align:center; width: 70px;" type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" value="{{$cartlist->product->productprice}}" > -->
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span id="subtotal">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</span>
                                </td>
```

Comment: Hi, claudia, that sounds like you're having a different problem now.  If my answer helped you with your current problem, can you mark it as correct, and then re-ask a new question, so I can look at it?  This helps people in the future who only have your first problem, etc..